# Como não jogar para pagina de resposta da API?

Tags: php, api

Ao clicar no botão que designei para comunicar com a API de telefonema, ele me joga para uma pagina onde confirma que tudo foi corretamente. Não qeroq  jogue pra essa pagina, o que eu poderia fazer, de preferencia em php?

não soube muito bem oq pesquisar para achar a resposta, espero ter sido claro.

```
<?php
session_start();
$celular = $_SESSION['celular'];
$ddd = $_SESSION['ddd'];
$zero = 0;
$num_com_zero = $zero.$ddd.$celular ; 
$num_s_zero = $ddd.$celular;
header("Location: http://201.76.188.6:8090/call.php?exten=7601&number=$num_com_zero");
?>
```

Comment: Mas você está, **literalmente**, redirecionando para a página da API. Isto é, o código faz somente aquilo que você não quer fazer, o que faz parecer que você não entende o código que você mesmo escreveu. O que exatamente você precisa fazer e por que fez desta maneira?

Comment: fiz dessa maneira, pq precisava fazer funcionar, porem, não esta na maneira perfeita q gostaria. Um empecilho é só tenho o link para enviar o numero por ele. o que eu realmente gostaria é de enviar esse numero pelo link e não ir para a tela de resposta da API, se manter na msm pagina q o cliente estava

Comment: é um botao "me ligue" onde o cliente clica e a api liga automaticamente para ele.

Answer (score 3):

Corrigi seu código usando CURL, verifique se é isso que deseja.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    session_start();
    $celular = $_SESSION['celular'];
    $ddd = $_SESSION['ddd'];
    $zero = 0;
    $num_com_zero = $zero.$ddd.$celular ; 
    $num_s_zero = $ddd.$celular;

    $url = "http://201.76.188.6:8090/call.php?exten=7601&number=".$num_com_zero;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    print $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Comment: eu uso php... é uma api limples, onde mando as informações por link

Comment: @PedroCastilho [CURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) é uma biblioteca PHP voltada para transferência de dados por meio de URL's.

Comment: Modifiquei minha postagem, modificando seu código para a utilização de Curl de uma olhada se é isso que deseja.

Comment: funcionou, porem da msm maneira q o meu, continua mudando pra pagina onde confirma q foi tudo feito corretamente... só q eu não queria q mudasse de pagina.. sera com com aquele curl q vc tinha posto antes, resolveria?

Comment: De uma pesquisa sobre Curl mais precisamente sobre CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION. Espero ter ajudado.